# Elementary Row Operation on Matrices and Column Space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

It is obvious that elementary row operations will not change the dimension of the row space of a matrix. But is there an easy way to understand that it also will not change the dimension of the column space? For example, I can understand that swapping two rows has no effect, because this is just to switch the order of two basis vectors in the column space. What about the other two operations?

Comment: Any thoughts on my answer, Kyson?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to see is that elementary row operations do not change linear dependence relations among the columns; pick a set of columns, they will be linearly dependent after the row operation if and only if they were dependent before the row operation. And the way to see this is to note that when you multiply the matrix by a vector, you get a linear combination of the columns of the matrix, the coefficients in the linear combination being the entries of the vector. So a linear dependence among the columns corresponds to an element of the nullspace, and row operations don't affect the nullspace (that's the idea behind using row operations to solve a system of equations).

Comment: Dear Gerry Myerson. Thank you for the answer. But how to show that the rank of the Column space will not change by row operations?

Comment: Those operations do not introduce any new linear dependencies among the columns, nor do they get rid of any linear dependencies among the columns, so they can't change the dimension of the column space. If you know all the linear dependence relations that hold among a collection of vectors, then you can calculate the dimension of the space spanned by those vectors.

Comment: I need some time to digest the whole thing. I am still confused about the meaning of the rows vectors. For the column vectors, the meaning is clear. We have a linear transformation from $F^n$ to $F^m$. The column vectors are just the images of the standard basis vectors of $F^n$. Do the row vectors have simple meaning of this kind?

Comment: The row vectors form a spanning set for the orthogonal complement of the kernel of the linear transformation. Row operations don't change the row space, so they don't change the dimension of the row space, so they don't change the dimension of the kernel, so they don't change the dimension of the image, so they don't change the dimension of the column space.

Comment: How do you define orthogonal complement? And how to show that the row vectors span this space?

Comment: The orthogonal complement of a subspace $V$ of ${\bf F}^n$ is the set of all elements of ${\bf F}^n$ orthogonal to all elements of $V$ (two vectors are orthogonal if their dot product is zero). The kernel of the transformation is the nullspace of the matrix representing the transformation, and being in the nullspace is the same as being orthogonal to each of the rows.

Comment: But a vector space is not required to have a dot product.

Comment: But ${\bf F}^n$ does have a dot product, defined by $$(a_1,\dots,a_n)\cdot(b_1,\dots,b_n)=a_1b_1+\cdots+a_nb_n$$

Comment: I prefer not to use the term inner product, which may not exist for general vector space $V$. I think it's better to consider the row vectors as elements in the dual space $V^*$, and the "orthogonal complement" of $K$, $K^\perp$, is the annihilator of $K$ in $V^*$. So it remains to show that $K^\perp$ is isomorphic to $(V/K)^*$. Do you agree?

Comment: I think that for the question of why elementary row operations don't change the dimension of the column space of a matrix, consideration of dual spaces and annihilators is overkill. What's behind all of this is that row rank equals column rank, and that falls out of reduced row-echelon form.

Comment: OK. Your argument is, row operation will not change row rank obviously. And because row rank equals column rank, it will not change column rank as well. Right?

Comment: That's a correct argument.

Comment: But does your proof of row rank equals column rank involve writing the matrix in reduced row-echelon form?

Comment: Yes, as I said, the equality of row rank and column rank falls out of reduced row-echelon form.

Comment: So that's circular argument and doesn't work, isn't it?

Comment: How do I know that the final column rank equals the initial column rank after the row operations. Similarly, how do I know that the final row rank equals the initial row rank after the column operations?

Comment: Huh? No one is doing any column operations.

Comment: OK. So how do I know the final column rank equals the initial column rank after the row operations?

Comment: OK. I think I will accept your proof at the beginning of our discussion. That is, the column space is the image, so it should be isomorphic and hence have the same rank as $V/K$. Row operations will not change $K$ and hence $V/K$, so although the image changes in row operations, but it should remain isomorphic to $V/K$, and therefore the rank with not change. However, is there an easier way to prove it by elementary (e.g., high school level) algebra?