# Why row operations do not change the columns space?

Tags: matrices

I understand why the elementary row operations do not change the row space, but why they do not change the column space (or at least the dependence between the columns)?

Comment: the same reason why column operations do not change the row space !

Comment: They *do* affect the column space (perform some row ops on $\bigl[ {1\ 0 \atop 1\ 0 }\bigr]$). To see why dependence relations are unchanged, look at the answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1144313/elementary-row-operation-on-matrices-and-column-space).

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332908/looking-for-an-intuitive-explanation-why-the-row-rank-is-equal-to-the-column-ran).